# Identifying ties in rank

Tags: quicksort

I am trying to create a program to rank numerical scores from highest to lowest.

```
for i in scores:
    if i[1] == max_score:
        print 'rank ', ctr,'highest score: {}  of {}'.format(i[1], i[0])
        pass

    if i[1] not in [max_score, min_score]:
        ctr= ctr+1
        print'rank ', ctr,'score: {} of {}'.format(i[1], i[0])
        pass



    if i[1] == min_score:
        ctr= ctr+1
        print 'rank ',ctr,'lowest score: {}  of {}'.format(i[1], i[0])
```

The text file contains:

```
john = 10
johnny=10
joseph = 9
j=9
jose = 8
q=7
```

However, the output of my code is:

```
rank  1 highest score: 10.0  of john 
rank  1 highest score: 10.0  of johnny
rank  2 score: 9.0 of joseph 
rank  3 score: 9.0 of j
rank  4 score: 8.0 of jose 
rank  5 lowest score: 7.0  of q
```

Comment: In the line `ctr= ctr+1`, you just increment each position. You never check whether the score matches the previous score.

Comment: Thanks for your help can you give me a guide how can i check the previous score if you dont mind ? thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I would do it:

```
ordered_score_values = sorted(set([s[1] for s in scores]), reverse=True)
for i in scores:
    ctr = (ordered_score_values.index(i[1])) + 1
    if i[1] == max_score:
        print 'rank ', ctr, 'highest score: {}  of {}'.format(i[1], i[0])

    if i[1] not in [max_score, min_score]:
        print 'rank ', ctr, 'score: {} of {}'.format(i[1], i[0])

    if i[1] == min_score:
        print 'rank ', ctr, 'lowest score: {}  of {}'.format(i[1], i[0])
```

The variable `ordered_score_values` for your example would contain `[10, 9, 8, 7]`. Here's why: `set` eliminates duplicates. `sorted` puts them in order, and `reverse` decides that the order is high-to-low.

Everyone's rank is computed the same way; we add the `+ 1` because the list is zero-indexed, but you would rather count from 1 than 0.

Comment: Thank u very much :) you are awesome :)

Comment: Was there something missing from my answer that caused you to un-accept it?

Comment: theres nothing wrong ur answer is very much correct thank u a lot ur great :)

Answer (score 0):

Although the answer is already accepted, I wanted to present a way using your given code. Your code updated ctr every time it passed the second if statement, which is why it kept counting up. You need a way to check if that score is equal to another score.

Add a helper variable (I used x) and give it a 0 value. In your second if statement, add another if statement checking to see if i[1] is less than x. If so, add 1 to ctr. At the very end, in your loop, set the x value to i[1].

```
scores={}
ctr=1
ctr1=2
ctr3=3

files=open("test.txt","r").readlines()
scores = [i.split('=') for i in files]
scores = [[i[0], float(i[1])] for i in scores]
scores = sorted(scores, key=lambda x: -x[1])

print scores
max_score = max([i[1] for i in scores])
min_score = min([i[1] for i in scores])

x = 0
for i in scores:
    if i[1] == max_score:
        print 'rank ', ctr,'highest score: {}  of {}'.format(i[1], i[0])
        pass

    if i[1] not in [max_score, min_score]:
        if i[1] < x:
            ctr = ctr + 1
        print'rank ', ctr,'score: {} of {}'.format(i[1], i[0])
        pass



    if i[1] == min_score:
        ctr= ctr+1
        print 'rank ',ctr,'lowest score: {}  of {}'.format(i[1], i[0])
    x = i[1]
```

This will do what you want based on your script, but there are definitely more efficient ways to do it.